# Extension of a nullhomotopic map into S^n

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

I don‘t understand the following argument in the paper „On the Steenrod homology theory“ by John Milnor:
Let $(X,A)$ be a compact pair (I think compact includes Hausdorff here), $f: \Delta^p \times A \to S^n$ a continuous nullhomotopic map ($\Delta^p$ is the standard $p$-simplex). Then we can extend $f$ to a map $\Delta^p \times X \to S^n$. (The argument is on p. 92)

Why can we find such an extension? I tried using Tietze, but I couldn‘t find a solution. Also the cofibration property would be enough, but I doubt we have it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $(X',A') = (\Delta^p \times X, \Delta^p \times A)$ is again a compact pair, thus it suffices to consider a continuous nullhomotopic map $f : A \to S^n$ and show that it extends to $X$.

More generally, let us consider a homotopy $h : A \times I \to S^n$ such that $h_0 = f$ and $h_1$ has an extension $H : X \to S^n$. We want to find an extension $F :  X \to S^n$ of $f$. This looks like the usual homotopy extension property, but the problem is that $A \hookrightarrow X$ is in general not a cofibration.

However, $S^n$ is an ANR (= absolute neigborhood retract) and therefore *Borsuk's homotopy extension theorem* applies. See

> Starbird, Michael. "The Borsuk homotopy extension theorem without the binormality condition." Fundamenta Mathematicae 87.3 (1975): 207-211.

You can read it [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm87/fm87117.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much! That indeed fixes every part of the problem