# Quotient of ENR by closed subset

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We say that a space $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an Euclidean Neighbourhood Retract, or ENR, if there is some $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that is a open neighbourhood of $X$ and a retract $r : A \to X$ (i.e., a continuous function that fixes all points of $X$). I am currently stuck on these two questions: (Originally from Lima's Fundamental Groups and Covering Spaces, page 22, question 14)

> If X is a ENR space and $F\subset X$ is closed, then $\frac{X}{F}$ is Hausdorff

> Further, if $F$ is contractible, then $\frac{X}{F}$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$.

My first attempt for the first question is the following: Let $\pi : X \to \frac{X}{F}$ be the quotient. For arbitrary $x_0\in X\setminus F$, we wish to find disjoint open neighborhoods $V_1$ of $\pi(x_0)$ and $V_2$ of $\pi(F)$. First take the distance $\varepsilon > 0$ between $x_0$ and $F$ (since $F$ is just a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and take the neighborhoods $U_1 = \{x\in X : d(x,x_0)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}$ and $U_2 = \{x\in X : d(x, F) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\}$. These are saturated open sets that should be mapped by the quotient $X \to \frac{X}{A}$ to the appropriate $V_1, V_2$.

There must be something wrong with this solution, since I only used the fact that $X$ is ENR in assuming $F$ is closed. For the second question, I am even more lost. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that $X/F$ is Hausdorff is true for any metric space and closed subset. Regardless of whether it is ENR or not. The second part is more interesting. Typical condition for the quotient map $X\to X/A$ to be homotopy equivalence is that $(X,A)$ has homotopy extension property. But I'm not sure why it holds here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $X/F$ is Hausdorff.

This is true for any regular Hausdorff space (= $T_3$ space) $X$.

Let $\xi_0 \in X/F$ denote the common  equivalence class all $x \in F$. Consider distinct points $\xi_1, \xi_2 \in X/F$.
If $\xi_1, \xi_2 \ne \xi_0$, we have $\xi_i = [x_i]$ with unique $x_i \in X$. Clearly $x_i \notin F$. Choose disjoint open neighborhoods $U_i$ of $x_i$ in $X$. Then the $V_i = U_i \setminus F$ are disjoint open neighborhoods of $x_i$ in $X$ and the $\pi(V_i)$ are disjoint subsets of $X/F$ such that $\xi_i \in \pi(V_i)$.  The $\pi(V_i)$ are open in $X/F$ because $\pi^{-1}(\pi(V_i))=  V_i$.
If one of the $\xi_i = \xi_0$, say $\xi_2 = \xi_0$, then choose disjoint open neighborhoods $U_1$ of $x_1$ and $U_2$ of $F$ in $X$. The sets $\pi(U_i)$ are then disjoint open neighborhoods of the $\xi_i$ in $X/F$.

2. The quotient map $\pi : X \to X/F$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Without any further assumptions on the pair $(X,F)$ this is true if the inclusion $i : F \to X$ is a *cofibration* ("standard theorem"). Unfortunately this is in general not true for pairs $(X,F)$ as in your question. However, it is *almost true*. In fact we have Borsuk's homotopy extension theorem. See [Extension of a nullhomotopic map into S^n](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739360). For the sake of completeness I shall give a proof for an ENR $X$ (Borsuk's theorem is slightly more general).

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be an $ENR$ and $(Y,B)$ be a pair of spaces such that $B$ is closed in $Y$ and $Y \times I$ is a normal space (= $T_4$ space). [This is satisfied for metric $Y$.] Then each continuous map $H : Y \times \{0\} \cup B \times I \to X$ has a continuous extension $\bar H : Y \times I \to X$.

*Proof.* By Tietze's extension each map $f : C \to \mathbb R$ defined on a closed subset $C$ of a normal space $Z$ has a continuous extension $F : Z \to \mathbb R$. Working coordinatewise, we see that this generalizes to maps $f : C \to \mathbb R^n$.

Hence $H : Y \times \{0\} \cup B \times I \to X \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ has a continuous extension $G : Y \times I \to \mathbb R^n$. Let $r : A \to X$ be a retraction as in your question. The set $U = G^{-1}(A)$ is an open neighborhood of $Y \times \{0\} \cup B \times I$ in $Y \times I$. Then $H' : U \xrightarrow{G} A \xrightarrow{r} X$ is a continuous extension of $H$. By the tube lemma there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $B$ in $Y$ such that $V \times I \subset U$. By normality of $Y$ (which follows from the normality of $Y \times I$) there exists a continuous $\phi : Y  \to I$ such that $\phi(y) = 0$ for  $y \in Y \setminus V$ and $\phi(y) = 1$ for  $y \in B$. The map
$$\bar H : Y \times I \to X, \bar H(y,t) = H'(y, \phi(x)t)$$
is the desired continuous extension of $H$. To see that $\bar H$ is well-defined, observe that all $(y, \phi(x)t) \in U$. In fact, for $y \in V$ we have $(y, \phi(x)t) \in V \times I \subset U$. For $y \in Y \setminus V$ we have $(y, \phi(x)t) = (y,0) \in Y \times \{0\} \subset U$. We have $\bar H(y,0) = H'(y,0) =  H(y,0)$ and  for $y \in B$ we have $\bar H(y,t) = H'(y,t) = H(y,t)$ which shows that $\bar H$ extends $H$.

The proof that $\pi$ is a homotopy equivalence can now be copied from the standard theorem for cofibrations. Here it is.

Let $h : F \times I \to F$ be a homotopy such that $h(x,0) = x$ and $h(x,1) = x_0$ for all $x \in F$. Define $H :  X \times \{0\} \cup F \times I \to X$ by $H(x,0) = x$ and $H(x,t) = h(x,t)$ for $x \in F$. $H$ has an extension $\bar H  : X \times I \to X$. Let $f : X \to X, f(x) = \bar H(x,1)$. We have $f(x) = x_0$ for $x \in F$, thus $f$ induces a continuous $f' : X/F   \to X$ such hat $f' \circ \pi = f$. We claim that $f'$ is a homotopy inverse for $\pi$.

(a) $id_X \simeq f$ via $\bar H$, thus $f' \circ \pi = f \simeq id_X$.

(b) $ \bar H(x,t) = h(x,t) \in F$ for all $x \in F$, thus $\bar H$ induces  a continuous $H' : (X/F) \times I \to X/F$ characterized by $H' \circ (\pi  \times id_I) = \pi \circ \bar H$. Note  that $\pi  \times id_I : X \times I \to (X/F) \times I$ is a quotient map because $\pi$ is one and $I$ is compact. With $\xi = \pi(x)$ we get
$H'(\xi,0) = \pi(\bar H(x, 0)) = \pi(x) = \xi$ and $H'(\xi,1) = \pi(\bar H(x,1)) = \pi(f(x)) = \pi((f' \circ \pi)(x)) = \pi(f'(\xi))$, i.e. $id_{X/F} \simeq \pi \circ f'$ via $H'$.